# Create datasource for Google BigQuery Plugin using the Grafana API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, grafana

##### Issue:

I would like to steer clear of using the traditional.

```
       authenticationType: jwt
       clientEmail: <Service Account Email>
       defaultProject: <Default Project Name>
       tokenUri: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
```

And use a service account json file from GCP. Is there anyway of doing this?

##### Environment:

OpenShift running in GCP. ServiceAccount key is mounted.

Comment: What's the error you are receiving?

Comment: Its not really an error so much as I would like to utilize the functionality that the UI has. It allows us to upload a service account key, but there is no way to automate that unless I strip apart the service account into the following. 
Client Email, default project, token uri, private key.

Comment: I want to just be able to add one.

```
apiVersion: 1
datasources:
- name: "Google BigQuery"
  type: doitintl-bigquery-datasource
  access: proxy
  secureJsonData:
       privateKey: $GCP_SERVICEACCOUNT_KEY
  version: 2
  readOnly: false
```

Comment: Where GCP_SERVICEACCOUNT_KEY is equal to something like below, this is the same thing you would paste into the UI to add/update the serviceaccount:
```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "demo-project",
  "private_key_id": "f871621360",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN RS...---.....",
  "client_email": "look-no-keys...iceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "102200000",
  "auth_uri": "https://a...uth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth.../token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.goog...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if understand your comments correctly, you want to create a BigQuery data source using the Grafana API.

This is the JSON body to send with your request:

```
     {
        "orgId": YOUR_ORG_ID,
        "name": NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_GIVE,
        "type": "doitintl-bigquery-datasource",
        "access": "proxy",
        "isDefault": true,
        "version": 1,
        "readOnly": false,
        "jsonData": {
            "authenticationType": "jwt",
            "clientEmail": EMAIL_OF_YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
            "defaultProject": YOUR_PROJECT_ID,
            "tokenUri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
        },
        "secureJsonData": {
            "privateKey": YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_KEY_FILE
        }
    }
```

So there is no way to avoid the code snippet you wanted to "steer clear of", however there is no need to take the JSON key file apart, just provide it to `privateKey`. You only have to provide the service account email additionally to `clientEmail` and the project id to `defaultProject`. Otherwise not different than using the UI.